# SetState on my overlay blinking the whole game on Flame

Tags: flutter, flame

I've just updated from Flame 1.0.0-rc8 to Flame 1.0.0-releasecandidate.14 but now my overlays (menu, score, etc...) can't be refreshed without blinking the game.

Here is a resume of my code:

```
class _Boat extends State<Boat> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  BoatGame game;


  @override
  void initState() {
    game = new BoatGame();
    refreshScore();
  }

  refreshScore() async {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 300), (timer) {
      if (mounted) {
        if (game != null) {
          score = game.getScore();
          setState(() {});
        }
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Stack(
      children: [
      GameWidget(game: game,),
      Text("My Score: $score");
    ],
  }
}
```

So, every 300ms, my screen is blinking and if I remove the SetState, the score isn't refreshed.

What's the solution ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know Flame, but have you considered using a `ValueNotifier` instead of updating you widget with `setState`? It can help because only the `Text` widget holding the score will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the refreshScore() like this :

```
 refreshScore() async {
timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 300), (timer) {
  if (mounted) {
    if (game != null) {
      setState(() {
      score = game.getScore();
       });
    }
  }
});
}
```

Then the setState would rebuild the state focused on your score.

Hope i could help :)

Comment: I don't see any difference between your code and mine :/

Comment: I'm so sorry, i didn't change the code and just explained what i thought would work. Now it's fixed. Sorry again

Comment: NP, I've already tried your new code before but the ValueNotifier solution seems to be working :)

Comment: @LuanSilva Is there an efficient way for calling `setState`  without triggering it every 300 milliseconds?